# while sending request from react frontend to node backend.Getting Login.jsx:38 Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Getting Login.jsx:38 Request failed with status code 404

My front-end is in react and backend is in express. Both are running on same ports.app url in front-end is correct. I am running both projects at same time and trying to connect the user info filled in front to check in from backend to login or send response.
This is my handle submit function in front end:

```
  const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Handle login functionality here
console.log("next")

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/login`, {
      user: username,
      pwd: password
    });

    // Check if user is admin and redirect accordingly
    if (response.data.role === 'admin') {
      window.location.href = '/login';
    } else {
      window.location.href = '/login';
    }
   } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // Handle error response
  }
  };
```

This is my endpoint in express:

```
app.post("/login", async(req, res) => {
    const questionsFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "model", "questions.json");
    const questionsData = await fsPromises.readFile(questionsFilePath, "utf-8");
    const questions = JSON.parse(questionsData);
    // req.session.username = username;
    const { user, pwd } = req.body;
    if (!user || !pwd)
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "Username and password are required.",
        });
    const foundUser = usersDB.users.find((person) => person.username === user);
    if (!foundUser)
        return res.status(409).render("login", {
            usrerror: "user not exists ",
        });
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(pwd, foundUser.password);
    if (!match) {
        return res.status(409).render("login", {
            pwderror: "wrong password ",
        });
    }

    //create jwt
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({
            username: foundUser.username,
            role: foundUser.role,
        },
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: "9000s" }
    );
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign({
            username: foundUser.username,
            role: foundUser.role,
        },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1d" }
    );

    res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "None",
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 9000 * 1000,
    });
    res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "None",
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });
    // res.redirect("/questions");
    res.json({ role: foundUser.role });

});
```